# Insert Into using a variable with multiple values as a parameter

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble using my array as a parameter.  I've imploded my array so it will display values with parentheses around them for example, list1 = (1),(2),(3)

```
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id Int NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO tmp (id) VALUES list1; //wont compile procedure
INSERT INTO tmp (id) VALUES (list1); //compiles however I can't put my array because the parentheses around the parameter ?
select * from tmp
END
```

Parameter -> Direction = IN, Name = list1, Type = Varchar, Length = 8000, Options=Charset

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would greatly be appreciated

UPDATE:

I dont think your understanding what I'm trying to accomplish. I have multiple values in list1 that im trying to insert. list1= (1),(2),(3) However the compiler only allows me to use list1 with parentheses around it even though I padded my string already with the neccessary parentheses. So then I tried using '1),(2),(3' but it only outputs 1 which is the first value

I dont have a problem insert into a temporary table, I have a problem using an array(list1) for the insertion....

Comment: Can you show us a minimal and complete example? Is this in a stored procedure? How is `list1` declared?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr it is a varchar(8000)

Comment: edit the question and show us the full code and error you get

Comment: if it is a varchar then its not an array in any way :D the concept of array is kinf of not-existent in database context

Comment: Please include a complete and minimal procedure to replicate the problem.

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr All I'm trying to do is insert multiple values from my array that I'm passing through.  The array can contain 1000 items or it can contain 5 items so I can't hardcode anything

Comment: @mikus I added more info to the question

Comment: so now its a temporary table, not an array, see how important is it to be preceise? just google it, its nothing new

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - INSERT INTO from a Temporary Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741627/mysql-insert-into-from-a-temporary-table)

Comment: @mikus I dont think your understanding what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have multiple values in list1 that im trying to insert.  list1= (1),(2),(3) However the compiler only allows me to use list1 with parentheses around it even though I padded my string already with the neccessary parentheses.  So then I tried using '1),(2),(3' but it only outputs 1

Comment: @mikus I dont have a problem insert into a temporary table, I have a problem using an array(list1) for the insertion....

Comment: you stil didnt show where is the list coming from... but from what i can see its not going to work like that, unless you create a dynamic sql,  other way around would be to use method to parse your varchar that you call array, run select on it and insert ... select to the tmp tablr

Comment: @mikus It works in php if I use mysql statements.  after converting it to a stored procedure, I noticed it doesn't like multiple values in a variable for the insert

Comment: if you create an sql query in a form of string in php and call it, of course it will work, it works as dynamic sql then, not something you cna directly bring to sql, the concept of array doesnt exist here, and throwing a single varchar(8000) in a place where interpreter expects a sequence of 'arrays' is clearly not going to work, how would it even know what to do with it? you either need dynamic sql or parse your serialized array to a form that sql understands ex. temporary table

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the full context, I don't know if this is the best solution, but it is a solution.

I've had success in similar case by using prepared statement. In your case, it could look like

```
  SET @stmt := CONCAT("INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES ", list1);

  PREPARE p_stmt FROM @stmt;
  EXECUTE p_stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE p_stmt;
```

Comment: Where? I just tested this example to double check and it works.

Comment: `CONCAT('INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES ', list1, ';');` Also it should be single quotes, not double quotes!

Comment: I agree that the single quotes could cause issues with other RDBMS and are preferable. The semicolumn is not necessary in this case, but it also doesn't cause problem to have it or not.